# Python3 script runs fine in Terminal but not as a crontab job

Tags: terminal, python

Using an iMac, Catalina. Recently changed ISP and need to know when feed was swapped over. New to Python scripting. I managed to get this running in Terminal, But not crontab.
Crontab reads:-

```
@reboot python3 terminal.py
Python script to give loud waring when internet connection is lost:-
#internet.py
import os
import time
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
var = 1
while var == 1 :
    rep = os.system('ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1')
    if rep == 0:
        #print ("Internet is UP")   #This line can be removed for no on screen activity.
        time.sleep(60)
    else:
        #print ("Internet is DOWN") #This line can be removed for no on screen activity.
        call(["osascript -e 'set volume output volume 100'"], shell=True)
        subprocess.call(["say","Lost Internet Connection"])
        call(["osascript -e 'set volume output volume 15'"], shell=True)
        time.sleep(60)  #Set to check connection every 60 seconds.
```

Comment: What are we looking at here? Which part of the code is your crontab entry, which is the script? What does „not running“ mean, do you get error messages?

Comment: I see two issues. First `cron` has its own environment with PATH set to `/bin:/usr/bin` so python3 isn't in your PATH. Second, `AppleScript (osascript)` usually requires the GUI to be running.

Comment: The Crontab is the first line @reboot. There is no error message. The error is the message 'Lost Internet Connection' been recited every 60 seconds. If I need a GUI to run it. I will just run it in Terminal and minimise it into the dock.